# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I keep getting this error. I understood it's a problem with the foreign key but i really can't understand what it's not working properly. I'm trying to make a many to many relationship with a bridge table. Please, if you can help me solve this! Here you can see the migrations:

Table dresses:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Dress extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('dresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('dress_id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('brand');
            $table->decimal('price');
            $table->string('fabric');
            $table->string('size');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('wash_instruction');
            $table->string('product_details');
            $table->string('fit');
            $table->rememberToken();;
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Table Wishlist:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Wishlist extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('wishlists', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('wishlist_id');
            $table->foreign('wishlist_id')
                ->references('user_id')
                ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }



    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Bridge table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateWishlistDressTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('wishlist_dress', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('dress_id');
            $table->foreign('dress_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('dresses')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('wishlist_id');
            $table->foreign('wishlist_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('wishlists')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('wishlist_dress');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your users migration set up? Do you have a column named users_id in the users migration file?

Usually, only the id column is used, which is generated from `$table->id()` in the users migrations file. I believe your migrations should work if you change from `users_id` to `id` like following:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Wishlist extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('wishlists', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('wishlist_id');
            $table->foreign('wishlist_id')
                ->references('id') //Changed from user_id to id
                ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }



    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```